# How to Mock Indexed Property with Rhino Mocks?

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

How can I Mock Indexed Property with Rhino Mocks ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a property using `this[]`

```
  var mockClass = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MockClass>();

  mockClass.Expect( m => m["key"] ).Return( "value" );  // return a value
  mockClass.Expect( m => m["key2"] = "value2" );  // set a value

  ... some test in here using something that depends on mockClass...


  mockClass.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Comment: I'm trying this 
    
mockClass.Expect(m => m[0]).Return(item); 

and I get an Index 0 is out of range.
Any ideas?

Comment: @Brian what type is `mockClass`?

Comment: mockClass is inherited from ConfigurationElementCollection and the error comes      
public Item this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BaseGet(index) as Item;
            }
            set
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(index) != null) //Fails Here even though its mocked/stub
                {
                    base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
                }
                this.BaseAdd(index, (ConfigurationElement)value);
            }
        }

Comment: That property isn't virtual so I suspect it may be using the property from the base class.  Is it possible to use a wrapper class around ConfigurationElementCollection rather than directly inheriting?  Mocking a wrapper is much easier than mocking a class descending from one that is not built with mocking in mind.